# Python plotting error bars with different values above and below the point

Tags: python, python-3.x, plot, graphing, distinct-values

Warning: I'm very new to using python.

I'm trying to graph data using error bars but my data has different values for the error above and below the bar, i.e. 2+.75,2-.32.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# example data
x = (1,2,3,4)
y = (1,2,3,4)

# example variable error bar values
yerr = 0.2

plt.figure()
plt.errorbar(x, y, yerr,"r^")
plt.show()
```

But I want the error bar above the point to be a specific value like .17 and below the point to be a specific point like .3
Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

Like this:

```
plt.errorbar(x, y, np.array([[0.3]*len(x), [0.17]*len(x)]), fmt='r^')
```

Pass an array of shape `(2,n)` with the -errors on the first row and the +errors on the second.

[image]

(Note also that you need to explicitly pass your format string `r^` to the `fmt` argument).

If you want different error bars on each point, you can pass them in this `(2,n)` array. You typically have a list of -err and +err value pairs for each data point in order, in which case you can build the necessary array as the transpose of this list:

```
yerr = np.array([(0.5,0.5), (0.3,0.17), (0.1, 0.3), (0.1,0.3)]).T
plt.errorbar(x, y, yerr, fmt='r^')
plt.show()
```

[image]

This is described (more-or-less) in [the docs](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.errorbar).

Comment: Thanks for answering! I have one more quick question. If each point has a different error bar value, what would I do? Like if the first point has values +.17 and -.3 but the second point in my data set has +.8 and -.23.

Comment: You use an array of shape (2,n) where each of the n pairs of values is the (-err, +err) for a point.